# Differentiate between all entrytypes in biblatex (e.g. mathesis vs. phdthesis)

Tags: biblatex, thesis

I recently switched to biblatex, which is so far great, but no as easy as bibtex.
I ran into a problem, which I couldn't solve so far:

My bibliography contains `reports, techreports, mastersthesis` and `phdthesis,` besides some `articles` and `books`.
As written in the biblatex doc, the first two are mapped with `@reports` and the third and fourth are mapped with `@thesis`. 
Reason behind this seems unclear and as I have different formatting option for the four entries, it is not possible to combine them.
The combination seems to be arranged in the `biblatex.def` under `\DeclareDriverSourceMap`
As I worked myself trough defining an own `*.bbx` file for custom bibliography style, I also defined different appearances for all the four entries.

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{ ...
...
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{phdthesis}{...
```

But still biblatex refers to the `biblatex.def` and ignores my entries.
How can I supress or renew the commands in the `\DeclareDriverSourceMap` section?
Preferred option would be to add some code in the `*.bbx` file, if not otherwise possible, also preamble would go. But with my MWE a redeclaration in the preamble seems to be not possible.

---

Here is the MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Beispielbibliographie.bib}
@PHDTHESIS{Mus15,
  Title                    = {Doktorarbeit ABC},
  Author                   = {Wax Mustermann},
  School                   = {XY Universität},
  Year                     = {2015},
  Note                     = {ISBN unbekannt},
}
@MASTERSTHESIS{Mus10,
  Title                    = {Bachelorarbeit DEF},
  Author                   = {Martina Musterfrau},
  School                   = {XY Universität},
  Year                     = {2010},
  Note                     = {Max Mustermann},
  Type                     = {unveröffentlichte Bachelorarbeit},
}
@ARTICLE{Gan11,
  Title                    = {GHI},
  Author                   = {T. Gantenbein},
  Journal                  = {Journal für Beispiele},
  Year                     = {2011},
  Number                   = {8},
  Pages                    = {1001-1010},
  Volume                   = {43},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents}{Beispiel.bbx}
\ProvidesFile{Beispiel.bbx}

\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelalpha,sorting=anyt}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelalpha}%
        \printfield{extraalpha}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelalphawidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\defbibenvironment{shorthand}
  {\list
     {\printfield[shorthandwidth]{shorthand}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\shorthandwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{mastersthesis}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{school}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit\newblock
  {}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{phdthesis}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{school}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  {}%
}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt,halfparskip,BCOR0pt,DIV12]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareDriverSourcemap[datatype=bibtex]{
  \map{
    \step[fieldset=day, null]
  }
}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, bibstyle=Beispiel, citestyle=alphabetic, firstinits=true, isbn=false, doi=false, url=false, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Beispielbibliographie.bib}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] \cite{Gan11,Mus10,Mus15}
\lipsum[2]

\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show us a short compilable code showing your own definitions and how you build the bibliography. Please add two bib entrys (report, phdthesis) and show the definitions the citing has to be ... Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The `xpatch` package defines the `\xpatchbibdriver`, `xpretobibdriver` and `\xapptobibdriver` commands to patch bib drivers.

Comment: I believe xpatch is not the optimal solution. Despite, that I have no MWE ready jet, I would hape hoped, that the answer would just be a redefinition of the `\DeclareDriverSourcemap` maps `\map{
    \step[typesource=techreport, typetarget=report, final]
    \step[fieldset=type,         fieldvalue=techreport]` etc. But I have noe clue on how to modiy them trough the `*.bbx`

Comment: In your MWE you definitely need to load `\DeclareDriverSourcemap` after you have loaded `biblatex`. Your examples confuse me even more: Your "B.Sc. thesis" is classed as `@phdthesis`, while the PhD thesis is a `@mastersthesis`? According to my tests you can even have `\DeclareDriverSourcemap` in the `.bbx` file and it still works. Note that all the fancy stuff you are using can only be used with `backend=biber` and not `backend=bibtex`. You need to switch.

Comment: Since you can't comment on your own question because you asked it with a different account, communication is a bit complicated. But what exactly are you missing from my answer below?

Answer (score 3):

You will find that `@techreport`s get mapped to `@report` with `type = {techreport}`, while `@phdthesis` and `@mastersthesis` both get mapped to `@thesis` with `type = {phdthesis}` and `type = {mastersthesis}` respectively. So there is a way to differentiate the types, just not via the entry type, but the `type` field.

I would have thought that the output for the types is sufficiently similar such that it would be enough to have one driver each (what exactly is the difference between the expected output for `@mastersthesis` and `@phdtehsis` except for the string that already indicates automatically if we have a MA or PhD thesis?), of course that depends on the exact output you seek, but you can check against the type with `\iffieldequalstr{type}{techreport}{Ohh, a @techreport}{just a normal @report}`.

For example

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printtext{\iffieldequalstr{type}{techreport}{Ohh, a @techreport}{just a normal @report}}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

---

If you absolutely must suppress the remapping in `biblatex.def` you can exploit the fact that `biblatex` can only ever accept one sourcemapping directive of any type. So if you add

```
\DeclareDriverSourcemap[datatype=bibtex]{
  \map{
    \step[fieldset=day, null]
  }
}
```

to the preamble of your document, the default mappings are ignored.